# How to verfiy postcode using php?

Tags: php

**I'm having postcode data in below format:**

[image]

I need to map customer with their provided postcode.

> EG. If customer enters postcode 36421 than it will assign to its
>   related representative that is "**John**".
>
> If customer enter postcode 36222 than it will assign to related
>   representative that is "**Sam**".
>
> If customer is from swiss country than it will assign to only one
>   representative  as per data in image.

I'm confused how can I map customer.

I also tried with **sub_str** like,

```
$postCode = $_POST['postcode'];
$postCode3Digit = substr($postCode, 0, 3);

But it breaks.
```

Also tried with **regex** but at same moment i think than I have to write **regex** for every single postcode :(

I tried with switch case but it seems to be taking more time.

What will be the best way to achieve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$postCode3Digit = substr(trim($postcode), 0, 3);`

Comment: @FAEWZX, I know I can trim values but its difficult to map it with customer when customer enters value that contains different dealer Take a look at given example and data.

Comment: FYI, _verifying_ post codes would be a very different thing from what you are actually asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I would look it up by using regex, because ZIP-data often are a little too complex for substr() only. So what I would do is to loop trough the persons and to compare the zip of the person with the zip-input. Keep in mind that you need to replace the X (in your script) with dots. Dots are recognized as one single character in regex.

```
$search = '34567';

$reps = array('adam' => '12...',
              'bdam' => '23...',
              'cdam' => '345..',
              'ddam' => '346..');

foreach($reps as $name => $zip){
 if(preg_match('/^'.$zip.'$/', $search)){
  echo $name; break;
 }     
}
```